# C# ReadLine Variable String to Int

Tags: c#

I have a statement and then the user has to enter a key.
If they enter one they do one thing and another, another thing.

From my Readline I have the problem where

> "error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'".

What's the problem with this because I think I have:

```
choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

**EDIT**

So now I have used Steve's answer (below)

This throws up this error message:

> CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

And for this line I think:

```
case 1:
  // action for choice == 1
  if(choice = 1|2)
     Console.WriteLine("Choice {0} Selected",choice);
  break;
```

Comment: You need to change the type of `choice` to `int`.

Comment: What type is `choice`?  If the error's cannot convert from int to string the issue's likely that `choice` is declared as a string.  If it's a string, simply do `choice = Console.ReadLine();`  If it's an int, what you have above should work fine.

Comment: choice is the variable name, above it is declared as string choice;

Comment: Thats your problem, change `string choice` to `int choice`

Comment: Make sure your `choice` is an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have:

```
string choice;
choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

since `Convert.ToInt32` returns an `int` you need to change the declared type of `choice` to `int` (or create a new variable).

```
int choice;
choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Okay so that works, but now my if statement doesn't and I get this: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Comment: @FettJ - Please add the information to your question.

Comment: Thanks! Using Convert.Int32() fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly caused by an incorrect assignment of an integer to a string variable. This could be remedied in many ways, but the biggest problem here is that you can't prevent your user to type anything (letters, puntuation, tabs) and blindly converting whatever user types to an integer is doomed from the beginning.

You should always program defensively in this scenario and use the appropriate conversion methods

```
int choice;
if(!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice))
   Console.WriteLine("You should enter a integer number");
else
{
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            // action for choice == 1
            break;
        case 2:
            // action for choice == 2
            break;
        default:
            // action for any other integer number
            break;
   }
}
```

[Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) will try to convert the input in a integer. If the input cannot be converted it returns false otherwise true.

**EDIT**

Following your edit, this line doesn't do what you think

```
if(choice = 1|2)
```

This line make a bitwise OR between the value 1 and the value 2 resulting in the value 3 then ASSIGN the value 3 to the variable *choice*. `if(3)` is not a boolean expression as required by the if statement.

See [C# Operator Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)

By the way, you don't need this code because inside the switch for *case 1*,  You already know the value of choice at this point and you can write directly

```
 Console.WriteLine("Choice {0} Selected",choice);
```

or whatever you want to do when choice == 1

Comment: Okay so that works, but now I get this: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool.

Comment: Where? In the code above there is nothing that tries to convert an int to a bool.

Comment: It's below as an if statement argument:  if(choice = 1|2)
    Console.WriteLine("Choice {0} Selected",choice);

Comment: But it's related to the previous question,   so for choice it throws up an error message telling me it can't convert int to bool despite that not being the case.

Comment: At least [edit] your question adding the code that throws this error.

Comment: Okay so I think I've implemented that but now when I compile and run, it allows me to enter the number and then doesn't display what I want in the Console. Writeline ().  What's the problem there?